# How to add a row to data frame (after conversion) in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I am trying to add a row to my data frame after I order it but I keep running into problems.

This is what I have tried:

```
colnames(col_freq) <- c("Symptoms", "values")
col_freq <- col_freq[order(-col_freq$values),]
top_freq <- rbind(col_freq[1:10,], c("Others", sum(col_freq[10:nrow(col_freq),2])))
```

The above code however results in the following data frame with a missing value

[image]

How do if add this row (`c("Others", sum(col_freq[10:nrow(col_freq),2]))`) to my data frame?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rbind` with `list` instead of a `vector` as `list` can have different types

```
rbind(col_freq[1:10,], list("Others", sum(col_freq[1:nrow(col_freq),2])))
```

With `c`, i.e. creating a `vector`, if there is a single non-numeric element, it would change the class of the whole vector to that type based on the order of precedence for different types.  `character` would have more precedence, so the `sum` output would be `character`

---

In the OP's code, the missing value would be generated if the first column is `factor`.  So, we need to convert that column to `character` or add a new level 'Others' before doing the `rbind`

```
col_freq$Symptoms <- as.character(col_freq$Symptoms)
```

Or if it needs to remain as `factor`

```
col_freq$Symptoms <- factor(col_freq$Symptoms, levels = c(levels(col_freq$Symptoms), "Others"))
```

Or assign new `level`

```
levels(col_freq$Symptoms) <- c(levels(col_freq$Symptoms), "Others")
```

Now, we do the `rbind`

```
rbind(col_freq[1:10,], list("Others", sum(col_freq[1:nrow(col_freq),2])))
#   Symptoms values
#1       fat     40
#2     sleep     25
#3     irrit     21
#4       rem     19
#5      Neck     18
#6      conc     12
#7      nerv     11
#8      Pres      9
#9      slow      9
#10     Head      8
#11   Others     172
```

#### data

```
col_freq <- data.frame(Symptoms = c("fat", "sleep", "irrit", "rem","Neck", "conc",
    "nerv", "Pres", "slow", "Head"), values = c(40, 25, 21, 19, 18, 12, 11, 9, 9, 8))
```